# Update Context Definition failed in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat6

I have installed apache tomcat 6.0 and imported my project on eclipse. I configured tomcat setting in eclipse but when I did update context definition for project. Eclipse give me error

Operation Failed
**C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\conf\Catalina\localhost\HMS.xml (Accss is denied) 
see  /.metadata/.log file**

Then I open log file in metadata i got this error

```
!SESSION 2013-05-24 09:08:34.477 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20100608-0911
java.version=1.6.0_45
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_IN
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

!ENTRY com.sysdeo.eclipse.tomcat 4 4 2013-05-24 09:09:31.134
!MESSAGE java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\conf\server.xml.backup (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sysdeo.eclipse.tomcat.FileUtil.copyFile(FileUtil.java:71)
    at com.sysdeo.eclipse.tomcat.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:62)
    at com.sysdeo.eclipse.tomcat.TomcatProject.backupServerXML(TomcatProject.java:755)
    at com.sysdeo.eclipse.tomcat.TomcatProject.updateServerXML(TomcatProject.java:651)
    at com.sysdeo.eclipse.tomcat.TomcatProject.updateContext(TomcatProject.java:639)
    at com.sysdeo.eclipse.tomcat.actions.UpdateTomcatContextActionDelegate.doActionOn(UpdateTomcatContextActionDelegate.java:16)
    at com.sysdeo.eclipse.tomcat.actions.TomcatProjectAbstractActionDelegate.run(TomcatProjectAbstractActionDelegate.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4066)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3657)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2629)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2593)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2427)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:670)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:663)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:574)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1407)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1383)
```

Please help me. 
Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a "Remove Context Definition" first

It worked for us just now after messing around for a few hours!